# How to make a trimmed histogram in R?

Tags: r, plot, histogram

I want to plot a histogram of some data. The data contains some extreme values or outliers so I would like to exclude these from the plot to get a meaningful picture of the bulk of the data. Here is some example data:

```
x <- c(seq(0, 1, 0.05)^2, 5)
hist(x)
```

You can't see anything about the distribution because of the one outlier. I could just manually exclude the outliers.

```
hist(x[x<2])
```

This is essentially what I want, but it requires me to define the exact cut off and is inconvenient if the data is not just x but some complicated expression. I would prefer to tell hist to trim of the largest and smallest few percent of the data similar to the trim option in the function mean.

I could also manually set the xlim and the breaks but that is even more awkward.

Is there a good intrinsic way to remove the most extreme values before plotting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps write a trimming function. This function removes outliers, which are defined as being greater than 1.5× the interquartile range from the mean. <s>(This is the definition of outlier used by Tukey's boxplots.)</s>

```
trim <- function(x){
  x[(x > mean(x)-1.5*IQR(x)) & (x < mean(x)+1.5*IQR(x))]
}

hist(trim(x))
```

[image]

Or, trim by percentile.

```
trim_q <- function(x, lb, ub){
  x[(x > quantile(x, lb)) & (x < quantile(x, ub))]
}

hist(trim_q(x, 0.01, 0.99))
```

This trims the data to between the first and ninety-ninth percentile.

[image]

---

### Edit

The first trimming function is not quite right. I think Tukey defined it at 1.5× the interquartile range above and below the first and third quartile and not the mean, as I did here. It should be as follows:

```
trim_t <- function(x){
  x[(x > quantile(x, 0.25)-1.5*IQR(x)) & (x < quantile(x, 0.75)+1.5*IQR(x))]
}

hist(trim_t(x))
```

[image]

Comment: Writing a small trim function is probably the best way to go. This way I could also use it for other plots or data analysis. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't exactly what you asked for, but it you want to literally trim a histogram, you can do that. In this case I remove the two most extreme bins. You can of course trim by many other rules.

```
set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(40)^3
x <- round(x, 1)*10

par(mfrow=c(2, 1), mar=c(3, 3, 0.1, 1))
h <- hist(x, main="")

h[1:4] <- lapply(h[1:4], function(y) head(y[-1], -1))
plot(h, main="")
```

[image]